# C# - No update in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a little problem, I'm trying update my listView(listClients)

```
private ListView initializeLstView()
        {
            var lstView = new ListView();
            var lstViewItem = new ListViewItem();
            for (uint i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
            {
                lstViewItem = lstView.Items.Add("Free");
                lstViewItem.SubItems.Add("Free");
            }
            return (lstView);
        }

        private ListView setNamesToLstView()
        {
            var lstView = initializeLstView();
            try
            {
                for (uint i = 0; i < 18; ++i)
                {
                    lstView.Items[(int)i].Text = clients.GetName(i);
                    lstView.Items[(int)i].SubItems[1].Text = "{" + i.ToString() + "}";
                }
                lstView.Update();               
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox(a.ToString());
            }
            return (lstView);
        }

        private void btnRefreshClients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listClients = setNamesToLstView(); // Here, no update
        }
```

But here, my listView contains nothing, no update / no refresh, why ? 
How can I resolve this ?

Comment: What is `listClients`?

Comment: listClients is my listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are adding items to another list view.

`listClients` is a member variable which points to a `ListView` which you previously added to `Controls` collection of your form. When you want to add items to that list view, you should add items exactly to that object using `listClients.Items.Add(...)`.

But currently you have created a `ListView` in the method and added items to it and at last returned it and assigned it to `listClients`. It doesn't make your new created list view be shown on your form. It makes `listClients` variable only points to new created control, Whilst you are seeing the previous created `ListView`.